# Import Entries with Categories

Tags: categories, import

I posted this on github already but I thought I would ask her as well to see if anyone has any ideas

Im trying ot do a simple import of some organizations with categories and parent organization

Here is the CSV

https://www.dropbox.com/s/irh8cno9eh536su/testImport.csv?dl=0

Everything goes in (including the parent which is an entry field and works great) but the categories always end up blank.

Any ideas what might be wrong?  The importer isnt showing any errors.

Comment: Which importer are you using?

Comment: Are you using this importer? https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import

Comment: Yup, sorry should have specified.  Are there other options to try that work with csv?

Answer (score 1):

Anyone curious about this answer, can checkout the GitHub thread referred to above:
https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import/issues/14

The most relevant comment for this answer is by `boboldehampsink`:

```
the documentation on category importing isn't complete yet. You have to fill in the complete path with titles, so: Category Title/Subcategory Title/Subsubcategory Title (for example)
```

Comment: Is that for only importing categories, or for importing entries with categories? I can't seem to get the categories to get set on entries when importing entries with categories.